# Identify device with android system

Tags: android

I read a lot of SO and blogs posts about unique IDs on android and can't find a good solution for my case. I want to have possibility to identify each device, i have a small app for internal use only. Idea is for each device to identify itself with ID so administrators can allow device to connect to the system. I know it is possible with `UUID` but this requires re authorization after each app reinstall and i would like to avoid this.

Comment: You could use device IMEI, since it's unique for each device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to use Android ID(Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)

- ANDROID_ID has a Different value for each app and each user on the device
- Value won't change on package uninstall/reinstall, as long as the package name and signing key are the same

But it may change if the device is factory reset or change signing key

```
 public static String getDeviceId(Context context) {
        return Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }
```

Link ref [Changes to Device Identifiers in Android O](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/changes-to-device-identifiers-in.html)
, [Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids)